# How to run django celery tasks with persistent event loop and asyncio calls with proper DB reconnections?

Tags: python, django, celery, python-asyncio, psycopg2

I have a django and celery, postgresql with psycopg2 driver and an external dependency with heavy setup calls which is hard to modify and which saves and reuses asyncio event loop after first invocation. I also have an asyncio call which I need to run in the celery task. This method uses this external dependency internally.

It seems that I can't use async_to_sync django call because it doesn't allow me to preserve the loop. Therefore, subsequent tasks executions raise `Event loop is closed` when I invoke dependency lib calls.

I used the following way to handle that:

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()

async def my_method():
    example_entry = await ExampleModel.objects.aget(id=1)
    # external async dep call here
    return example_entry

@shared_task(name="example_task", bind=True)
def example_task(self):
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(my_method())
```

It has worked perfectly for a few months, until we had a restart of the database and connection was lost. All further tasks had `django.db.utils.InterfaceError: connection already closed` error.

Digging in, I created a set of test tasks:

```
@shared_task(name="debug_task_async_to_sync")
def debug_task_async_to_sync(self):
    import asgiref.sync
    res = asgiref.sync.async_to_sync(my_method)()
    print("async_to_sync", res)


@shared_task(name="debug_task_loop")
def debug_task_loop(self):
    res = utils.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(my_method())
    print("loop", res)


@shared_task(name="debug_task")
def debug_task():
    res = models.ExampleModel.objects.get(id=1)
    print("sync", res)
```

and restarted the database in the time of their execution.

Both sync `debug_task` and `debug_task_async_to_sync` reconnect to the database. `debug_task_loop` stops executing for all subsequent invocations. Moreover, it happens simultaneously (e.g. non-"loop" tasks recreate the connection at the same time as the "loop" one keeps failing).

Is there any way to either preserve the event loop for the external lib with async_to_sync or handle reconnections to the database correctly?